# Selenium Grid2 Print Screen

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

I was wondering how people have gone about getting screenshots from a selenium grid test.  Presumably my screenshot will be saved to the machine the selenium node is running on, how can I then get it back to a common location?  Ideally I want my images to all be in the work directory in Jenkins...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot is saved to the machine the machine you're executing the tests on, not the grid nodes. We are not using Jenkins, but using a Ruby environment.

```
#Ruby Screenshot
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :ie
driver.get "https://www.google.com"
driver.save_screenshot("./screen.png")
```

The screenshot is stored on the machine where you instantiate the webdriver from that instance of the webdriver connects to the selenium grid.  I believe there is an environment variable in Jenkins that allows you to set where they are stored.  I have a limited knowledge of Jenkins though.

Comment: That's awesome, I didn't realize.  Sorry that this was a non-question then, I wanted to find out before it was fully implemented in case there was a lot of extra work required.